# Apply reduce on generator output with multiprocessing

Tags: python, generator, python-multiprocessing

I have a generator function (Python) that works like this

```
def Mygenerator(x, y, z, ...):
    while True:
        # code that makes two matrices based on sequences of input arrays
        yield (matrix1, matrix2)
```

What I want to do is to add the output from this generator. This line does the job:

```
M1, M2 = reduce(lambda x, y: x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1], Mygenerator(x, y, z, ...))
```

I would like to parallelize this to speed up the computations. It is important that the outputs from Mygenerator is reduced as it is yielded, since `list(Mygenerator(...))` would take too much memory.

Comment: `x[0] and y[0]` are numbers or something else?

Comment: x[0] and y[0] are matrices. The generator returns (matrix1, matrix2), and the reduce operation adds together the matrix1's and matrix2's from consecutive calls.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here. Did  you mean to have parenthesis around the lambda like: `reduce((lambda x, y: x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]), Mygenerator(x, y, z, ...))`. I wont even comment on `while True` in the generator ;)

Comment: I'm trying to iterate over segments of x, y, and z (etc.) and compute matrix1 and matrix2 for each segment. The lambda expression returns the sum of the `matrix1`s and `matrix2`s. I have found a solution, which is posted below

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question, I found a solution that seems to work as I had hoped:

First, `Mygenerator` is no longer a generator but a function. Also, instead of looping through segments of x, y and z, I now pass one segment to the function at the time:

```
def Myfunction(x_segment, y_segment, z_segment):
        # code that makes two matrices based on input arrays
        return (matrix1, matrix2)
```

Using `multiprocessing.Pool` with the `imap` (generator) function seems to work:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(ncpus)
results = pool.imap(Myfunction, 
                    ( (x[i], y[i], z[i]) for i in range(len(x)) )
M1, M2 = reduce(lambda r1, r2: (r1[0] + r2[0], r1[1] + r2[1]), 
                    (result for result in results))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

where I changed the `x` and `y` in the lambda expression to `r1` and `r2` to avoid confusion with the other variables with the same name. When trying to use a generator with  `multiprocessing` I got some trouble with pickle.

The only disappointment with this solution is that it didn't really speed up the computations that much. I guess that has to do with overhead operations. When using 8 cores, the processing speed was increased by approximately 10%. When reducing to 4 cores the speed was doubled. This seems to be the best I can do with my particular task, unless there is some other way of doing the parallelizing...

The `imap` function was necessary to use here, since `map` would store all the returned values in memory before the `reduce` operation, and in this case that would not be possible.